# When I go to ask a question, I get "Comments must be at least 15 characters in length." and I can't submit the question

Tags: support, error-message

When I go to ask a question, I get "Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.",  and I can't submit the question. I have tried in Chrome, Chrome Incognito, and Firefox. This seems like a bug with server side validation.

Comment: Won't answer the question yet, but someone should be along shortly.